# How can I have treesitter have a decent visual fallback when it panics?

Tags: plugin-treesitter

Treesitter is very often panicking and refusing to parse stuff on my Windows machine. How can I survive this and still be able to modify the file smoothly, maybe by falling back to some more basic syntax highlighting?